# enable leverage browser caching in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, caching, web-config

I use this code in web.config for enable leverage browser caching in web site

```
<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
```

What caching by this code? (Only images?)

What are the possible risks of using this code?